# Saving Multiple Plots with Different Names

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to save multiple plots to a directory. Problem is, I don't want to use a counter for the different file names because they all have different ID numbers, denoted as trk_id, or j. If you need more of the code, please let me know! Plus, I know this code just uses the same name and overwrites each file.

```
  for i, j in enumerate(trk_id):
          t = np.arange(0, 3*3600) + t0_b[i]
          g_x = f_r(tau_b[i], t0_b[i], c0_b[i], c1_b[i], c2_b[i])
          fig,ax = plt.subplots()
          ax.plot(t, g_x(t))
          plt.yscale('log')
          plt.ylabel('Height (arcsec)')
          plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
          ax.set_title(j)
          plt.savefig('plots/j.png')
```

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. If the code you show is not a [mcve] of the code you actually want to use, how should anyone know the actual problem? Plus, you forgot to tell us the actual problem.

Comment: My apologies. This loop generates a plot of specific parameters from multiple lists. I figured putting the entire code would be a nightmare on other's ends. The issue is when I'm saving each plot, they're all being saved under the same name and are overwriting each other, so at the end, I'm left with one plot, the final plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use the loop variable `j` as filename, you can generate a string like

```
filename = 'plots/' + str(j) +'.png'
plt.savefig(filename)
```

or

```
filename = 'plots/{}.png'.format(j)
plt.savefig(filename)
```