# How can I save several plot with different names coming from loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, save

I am new in python. I am doing a loop for plotting the same figure for many countries which belong to a list. When I tried to save the plot in a path I specified, the plot saved is just the last one. How can I save every single plot with different name which come from each interaction and change according to the plt.title? Figures are showed in the cell, but I can't save them.

```
for c in countries_list:     
    ax = emissions.loc[c].T.plot(kind='area', rot= 0, stacked=True)     
    plt.title('Emissions of' + ' ' + c, fontsize='14', fontname="sans")     
    plt.savefig('../plots/test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Note that you keep using the same file name inside your loop, so you keep overwriting the file contents

Comment: Change `plt.savefig('../plots/test.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')` to `plt.savefig('../plots/test_{}.pdf'.format(c), bbox_inches='tight')`

Comment: More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44959319/saving-multiple-plots-with-different-names)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give each plot a unique name. Otherwise each plot overwrites the last which is why your only getting the last.

Try:

```
'../plots/test' + '-' + c + '.pdf'
```

Comment: @roganjosh changed them to single quotations.

Comment: Double quotes would also be valid, but you used some fancy quote characters that wouldn't be recognised :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that detail. I definitely over looked it. My original post was from my iPhone and their go to is fancy quotations it seems. But I normally like single quotations and edited it on my laptop.

Comment: Aha, I'm spotting a theme across answers. The iphone double quotes translate to some invalid characters (for Python) on SO

Comment: To fix it all you have to do is turn off "Smart Punctuation"!

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
for index, c in enumerate(countries_list):     
    ax = emissions.loc[c].T.plot(kind='area', rot= 0, stacked=True)     
    plt.title('Emissions of' + ' ' + c, fontsize='14', fontname="sans")     
    plt.savefig('../plots/test-{0}.pdf'.format(index), bbox_inches='tight')
```

hence, every time the name of the pdf where you are save the plot is gonna be different.